# ios assets not work on ios5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, assets

here is my code:

```
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                        usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                        failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                            NSLog(@"Failure");
                    }];
```

my previous code is this:

```
assets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];



void (^assetEnumerator)( ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    if(result != NULL) {
        NSLog(@"See Asset: %@", result);
        [assets addObject:result];

    }
};

void (^assetGroupEnumerator)( ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group != nil) {
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
 };


ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
```

and with my phone (ios5) doesn't work, can't go to the assetGroupEnumerator...
also in the simulator, the same thing....
any ideas?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you releasing your `ALAssetsLibrary` before you are done displaying the assets? You need to retain the library throughout the lifetime of the groups and assets you are using.

Comment: The simplest would be to make a retaining property on your object and assign it to that, i.e., `self.library = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease]`, and only set `self.library = nil` when you are completely done with the assets.